# Forms ModelChoiceField display

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to build a simple form to linked to two models-tables.
Here are my model declaration :

model.py

```
class THost(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)
    Location = models.ForeignKey('TLocation', db_column='idLocation')

class TLocation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)
    address = models.TextField(blank=True)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)
```

My forms.py

```
class hostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    Location = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=TLocation.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = THost
```

My views.py

```
   form1 = hostForm()
   if request.method == "POST":
      form1 = hostForm(request.POST)
      if form1.is_valid:
        form1.save()
```

The problem is that in the form i have now a drop down list displaying several lignes with : "TLocation object".
I cannot figure out how to simply display the TLocation name or city

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your models.py:

at the top:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

Before your model classes:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class YourModel(models.Model):
```

and inside your model class:

```
def __str__(self):
    """
    Return the representation field or fields.
    """
    return '%s' % self.name
```

Comment: That's a bit roundabout. OP presumably knows whether he is targeting Python 2 or 3. Leave out the import and the decorator, and if 2, implement `__unicode__`, and if 3, then implement `__str__`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes but in the case he is contributing or either working with others, it's not a bad habit to keep consistency :)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @petkostas ! I was looking for something complexe and python is not :)

Here is was i putted :

```
class TLocation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)
    address = models.TextField(blank=True)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s - %s' % (self.name, self.city)
```

The result is a drop down list with "name - city"

Brilliant thank you

Answer (score 0):

try to customized  ModelChoiceField and override label_from_instance. This method will receive a model object, and should return a string suitable for representing it:

```
class MyModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.name


class hostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    Location = forms.MyModelChoiceField(queryset=TLocation.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = THost
```